# Issue when putting a JLabel inside a Swing table

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to put a `JLabel` inside my Swing `JTable` but what I get is apparently the name of the object instead:

[image]

This is the class I used to load the `JLabel` into my table:

```
    /**
       * Main Class.
       */

    public class Test extends JFrame {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private JPanel contentPane;
      private MyTable tableDest;
      private MyTable tableSource;

      /**
       * Launch the application.
       */
      public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          @Override
          public void run() {
            try {
              Test frame = new Test();
              frame.setVisible(true);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
          }
        });
      }

      /**
       * Create the frame.
     * @throws Exception 
       */
      public Test() throws Exception {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
        setContentPane(contentPane);

        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane();
        splitPane.setResizeWeight(0.5);
        contentPane.add(splitPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        tableSource = new MyTable(true);
        splitPane.setRightComponent(tableSource);

        tableDest = new MyTable(false);
        splitPane.setLeftComponent(tableDest);


        TransferHandler transferHandler = new MyTransferHandler();

        tableSource.setDragEnabled(true);
        tableSource.setTransferHandler(transferHandler);
        tableSource.setDropMode(DropMode.ON);


        tableDest.setDragEnabled(true);
        tableDest.setTransferHandler(transferHandler);
        tableDest.setDropMode(DropMode.ON);
      }
    }


     /**
       * Class for The Table
       */


      class MyTable extends JTable {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      public MyTable(boolean withData) throws Exception {
        this( new MyTableModel(withData));
      }

      public MyTable(MyTableModel tableModel) {
        super(tableModel);
        setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
      }

      @Override
      public MyTableModel getModel() {
        return (MyTableModel)super.getModel();
      }
    }

    /**
       * Class for The JPanel import into The table
       */

    class MyTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

      private JLabel[] dataSource = new JLabel[16];

      public MyTableModel(boolean fill) {
        if(fill) {
          for(int i = 0; i < dataSource.length; i++) {
            dataSource[i] = new JLabel("<html>Text color: <font color='red'>red</font></html>");
          }
        }
      }

      @Override
      public int getRowCount() {
        return 4;
      }

      @Override
      public int getColumnCount() {
        return 4;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        int index = getIndex(row, col);
        return dataSource[index];
      }

      @Override
      public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int col) {
        int index = getIndex(row, col);
        dataSource[index] = (JLabel)aValue;
      }

      @Override
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return JLabel.class;
      }

      public void removeAt(int row, int col) {
        int index = getIndex(row, col);
        dataSource[index] = null;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
      }

      private int getIndex(int row, int col) {
        return row*4 + col;
      }
}

    /**
       * Class for the drag'n drop Stuff
       */

     class MyTransferHandler extends TransferHandler {

      private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


      @Override
      public int getSourceActions(JComponent comp) {
        return MOVE;
      }

      int selectedRow;
      int selectedCol;


      @Override
      public Transferable createTransferable(JComponent comp) {
        System.out.println("createTransferable");

        MyTable table = (MyTable)comp;
        selectedRow = table.getSelectedRow();
        selectedCol = table.getSelectedColumn();

        String text = (String) table.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedCol);
        System.out.println("DND init for: " + text);
        return new StringSelection(text);
      }

      @Override
      public void exportDone(JComponent comp, Transferable trans, int action) {
        System.out.println("exportDone");

        if (action == MOVE) {
          MyTable table = (MyTable)comp;
          table.getModel().removeAt(selectedRow, selectedCol);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public boolean canImport(TransferSupport support) {
        //System.out.println("canImport");
        return support.isDrop();
      }

      @Override
      public boolean importData(TransferSupport support) {
        System.out.println("importData");
        if(canImport(support)) { //to prevent from paste's

          DropLocation dl = support.getDropLocation();
          Point dropPoint = dl.getDropPoint();

          String data;
          try {
              data = (String)support.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
              System.out.println("DND received: " + data);
          } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
              return false;
          }

          MyTable table = (MyTable)support.getComponent();
          int row = table.rowAtPoint(dropPoint);
          int col = table.columnAtPoint(dropPoint);

          MyTableModel model = table.getModel();
          Object currentValue = model.getValueAt(row, col);
          if(currentValue == null) { //if there's currently no value on that cell
            model.setValueAt(data, row, col);
            model.fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? It's not supposed to display a `JPanel` instead of this text.

Comment: @AndrewThompson done, I'm sorry for the mistake

Comment: That last sentence is *not a question*..

Comment: BTW - For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  (One code source file, not 4.)

Comment: Yes but the problem I don't know from where comes the Issue ..

Comment: *"I don't know from where comes the Issue"*  So put all 4 classes into a **single source code file**!  (Note, one source file can have many classes, but a maximum of *one* `public` class.)  But make sure the code presented to others actually **compiles** - that code seems to be missing at least the `PiecesDao` class.

Comment: Note the last part of my (edited) comment.  Make sure the copy/paste sample provided actually *compiles* when copied to a fresh project in the IDE.

Comment: The PieceDao class have too many dependency's ( more than 30 class ) but I'm pretty sure that PieceDao works well because when I test this jpanel.add(jpiece); with a seperate frame it provides what I'm looking for the problem is when I try to add this JPanel which contain the jpiece to the table

Comment: *"I'm pretty sure that PieceDao works well"*  So factor it out of the code entirely.  If it's working, it shouldn't be in an MCVE!

Comment: *"this is the github repository"*  If it is an MCVE, post it here.  If it's not, I'm not going to visit an external URL to download the various parts!  Voting to close..

Comment: I can't post The hole code of PieceDao ( more than 30 classes ) and the Issue doesn't lies with PieceDao I'll re post a code who doesn't depend on this class

Comment: @AndrewThompson code Edited now It doesn't depend on PieceDao

Comment: What exactly does `MyTransferHandler` class have to do with the stated problem?  Can the problem be demonstrated without it?  If so, it shouldn't be part of an MCVE!  (BTW - please include the imports in an MCVE. Package imports will do unless individual classes clash).

Comment: Always nice to come to a question after the MCVE massacre has ended and it is ready to be answered.

Comment: I take it back, it's just a CVE. Start chopping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to put a JLabel inside my Swing Table but what I get is apparentely the Name of the object instead.

`JLabel` is the default component for a cell in a `JTable`. I assume you added a `JLabel` to the default one, which caused its `toString` method to be invoked and displayed in the default label.

[image]

Here I created a new `JTable` and put your `String` in all the cells:

```
public class Test extends JFrame {

    static String data = "<html>Text color: <font color='red'>red</font></html>";
    static int size = 4;

    public Test() {

        JTable table = new JTable(size, size);
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                table.getModel().setValueAt(data, i, j);
            }
        }
        add(table);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new Test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help , and supposing that "data" was not a string a shape instead , what to do ?

Comment: @ZeRubeus Draw the shape on the cell component (the default `JLabel` in this case).